# how remove tag (which contains special tag ) via xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have following xml.

```
<rules>
  <rule>
    <name>aa</name>
  </rule>

  <rule>
     <name>bb</name>
  </rule>

  <rule>
    <name>cc</name>
  </rule>
</rules>
```

I would like to remove rule which name is 'bb' via xslt. So the output should be -

```
<rules>
      <rule>
        <name>aa</name>
      </rule>


      <rule>
        <name>cc</name>
      </rule>
</rules>
```

I have tried this , but it does not work.

```
 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="//rules[rule[name[text()='bb']]]">

</xsl:template>
```

Thanks.

Comment: "does not work" - in what way? looking at the match argument, its probably removing the rules element and not the specific rule?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove the specific rule element which has a name element, which has the text, all you should need in your match is:

```
<xsl:template match="rule[name[text()='bb']]">
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works now !. Yes actually I was deleting <rules> tag via that xslt.